# How to merge two json files using google GSON in java?

Tags: java, json, merge, gson

this is file1.json

```
 [
{
"name": "Leonard",
"age": 28,
"city": "Pasadena"
},
{
"name": "joey",
"age": 29,
"city": "NewYork"
}]
```

this is file2.json

```
 [
{
"name": "Shelly",
"age": 28,
"city": "LA"
},
{
"name": "Chandler",
"age": 29,
"city": "NewYork"
}]
```

So, how to merge these 'file1.json' and 'file2.json' into a single file by using the google GSON library in java?

Comment: merge how? like in one big list?

Comment: If you mean "concatenate", then it's easy, but not out of box. But let me ask you: what did you try yourself and why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: yes, Sir@RobAudenaerde in one list.

Comment: Sir@fluffy I want to try to concatenate or merge in a single file as a list. I am preparing some JSON manipulation for my test/interview.

Comment: @HuidromPunendrajitSingh well, will we be with you at the interview? No, so this is why I was asking for providing the code that _does not work_ for you to see _how you_ see it. By the way, I can tell you that the currently only answer is far from being perfect: it's too ad-hoc, it violates resource management rules, it uses unnecessary deserialization (that is not guaranteed to make a perfect round-trip), it has mistakes in use of generics... Well, yeah, be aware.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`List.addAll()` may solve the problem, partially. If the same object appears in both JSON files, you may end up with duplicated objects in the result. Say you want each object in the array to be considered "distinct" by a specific key (e.g.: "name"). Then you should take a look at [jsonmerge](https://obvj.net/jsonmerge).

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that the output you require is a new file with a single array of objects.

Following is the code required to achieve that :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

JsonReader reader1 = new JsonReader(new FileReader(new File(/path of "file1.json"/)));

List<String> data1 = gson.fromJson(reader1 , List.class);

JsonReader reader2 = new JsonReader(new FileReader(new File(/path of "file2.json"/)));

List<String> data2 = gson.fromJson(reader2, List.class);

data1.addAll(data2);

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(/path of the output file/);

gson.toJson(data1 , fileWriter);

fileWriter.flush();

fileWriter.close();
```

***JsonReader*** reads a JSON encoded value as a stream of tokens. The tokens are traversed in depth-first order, the same order that they appear in the JSON document.

***fromJson*** reads the JSON value from the reader and converts it to the type given in the second argument i.e., ***java.util.List***

After we get the list from both the JSON files, we merge them by using ***addAll*** method of ***java.util.List*** package.

We take the merged list and use ***toJson*** to serialize the specified list into its equivalent JSON representation.

The JSON in the new file is as follows :

```
[{"name":"Leonard","age":28.0,"city":"Pasadena"},{"name":"joey","age":29.0,"city":"NewYork"},{"name":"Shelly","age":28.0,"city":"LA"},{"name":"Chandler","age":29.0,"city":"NewYork"}]
```

Comment: thanks, Sir its works this is what I am looking for.